# Добавление буквы в случайный элемент

Tags: javascript

Нужно чтобы компьютер после хода человека (вызова функции click1)  сгенерировал случайное число от 1 до 9, подставил к "s" и проверил, если там пусто поставил "Y", если занято - повторно сгенерировать число...
в коде какая-то проблема не могу понять:

```
var s1 = document.getElementById("s1")
var s2 = document.getElementById("s2")
var s3 = document.getElementById("s3")
var s4 = document.getElementById("s4")
var s5 = document.getElementById("s5")
var s6 = document.getElementById("s6")
var s7 = document.getElementById("s7")
var s8 = document.getElementById("s8")
var s9 = document.getElementById("s9")
var comChoice=0;
var clickScore=0;

function click1(element){
    clickScore++
    comChoice =  Math.floor((Math.random() * 9)+1);
    console.log(comChoice)
    if(element.innerText==""){
        if(clickScore%2==1 ){
            element.style.cursor= "default"
            element.style.color="white"
            element.style.fontSize="40px"
            element.style.textAlign="center"
            element.innerHTML="X"
        } else{
            element.style.cursor= "default"
            element.style.color="white"
            element.style.fontSize="40px"
            element.style.textAlign="center"
            element.innerHTML="O"
        }
    } else {
        alert("Ячейка  уже занята")
    }

    computerTurn()

    if (proverka()==true ){
        alert("end")
    }
}


function computerTurn(){
    comChoice =  Math.floor((Math.random() * 9)+1);
    if (s[comChoice].innerHTML=="X"||s[comChoice].innerHTML=="Y"){
        computerTurn()
    } else {
        s[comChoice].innerHTML=="Y"
    }
}
```

Comment: советую к прочтению [справку о массивах](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array)

Comment: @Lucky_girl, плохая идея менять код в вопросе, в котором нужно узнать _почему_ код не работает

Comment: @Grundy, а я не меняла код в вопросе, я исправляла орфографию и пунктуацию.

Comment: @Lucky_girl, был перенесен вызов `clickScore++` в начало функции

Comment: @ИванПшеницын, поэтому обращение не к тебе,а к @Lucky_girl :)`

Comment: @Тигран - "в коде какая-то проблема" - не определены функция `proverka` и массив `s`.

Comment: @Igor, `proverka` определена :-) про нее было уже несколько вопросов

Comment: оффтоп: автор, за что вы так не любите точку с запятой?) У вас их катострофически не хватает: https://goo.gl/JkG9f2 (желтым подсвечены предупреждения).

Comment: @ИванПшеницын, обрати внимание что последние строчки условий не подсвечены, хотя в них тоже отсутствует `;`. Ну и автор, наверное, не попадал в ситуацию, когда все вдруг сломалось только из-за того, что отсутствовала `;`

Comment: @Grundy да, ведь последнюю т.с.з. можно не ставить

Comment: @ИванПшеницын, любую точку с запятой можно не ставить.

Comment: @Grundy я предпочитаю следовать общепринятым стандартам, пусть и не официальным. [JSLint](http://www.jslint.com/) не зря писали. Не ставить последнюю принято в той же мере, что и ставить все остальные. Или вы настаиваете, что код - простор для творчества и нужно давать волю фантазии?)

Comment: @ИванПшеницын, я считаю, что код должен быть однообразен, и раз уж ставишь `;` ставь ее везде

Comment: @Grundy в таком случае, мы придерживаемся одного мнения. просто я вас неверно понял.

Comment: @Grundy  щяс всё прочту и напишу ( инет пропал )

Comment: @Igor это функция у меня имеется , на нормально работает , забыл просто удалить здесь , но на самом деле не она проблема ,

Comment: @ИванПшеницын пока что стараюсь просто не забывать про точки с запятыми :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Проблема в отсутствии переменной `s`. А так как ее нет, к ней нельзя обращаться

```
s[comChoice]
```

Следовательно стоит ее завести, например так

```
var s = [s1,s2,s3,s4,s5,s6,s7,s8,s9];
```

Стоит учитывать, что в данном случае индексация будет начинаться с 0, следовательно в расчете ячейки не нужно добавлять 1

```
comChoice =  Math.floor(Math.random() * 9);
```

Comment: на самом деле за  это время я это и делал (сделал масив, а в матрандоме удалил "+1"),,я не совсем понимаю один момент, как может функция вызвать сама себя, например если с помощью мат рандома проверяет есть ли символ в элементе , скажем если уже занято , как снова сгенерировать число и снова вызвать эту функцию (получается будет сама себя вызывать)

Comment: @Тигран, [Рекурсия](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A0%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%83%D1%80%D1%81%D0%B8%D1%8F), Ну и конкретно тут можно было циклом обойтись: пока занято - получай координату

Comment: сейчас попробую , и не по этой теме но всё же не понятно , почему в if (proverka()==true ) если написать без "true" то есть   if (proverka() ) (это же в принципе одно и то же ) то не работает так ?

Comment: @Тигран, не знаю почему может не работать, записи эквивалентны

Comment: благодарю, наверно что-то не правильно делал